# iptable does not block port 80, rule does not work

Tags: iptables

I have configured my iptable to block port 80, but still I can access port 80 from outside the machine, why is that ? by the way I have tested the ssh 22, if I am not from network 192.168.111.0/24 then the rule works just fine, but for http 80 does not work at all,

here is my simple rule:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.111.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
5    REJECT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 ctstate ESTABLISHED
3    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```